# Android slow GPU rendering speed issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, responsive, freeze

I got stuck in one issue from many days.When i lock/unlock home screen 3-4 times, it freezes.It is working fine with RAM having more than 3 GB.

I have base activity and activity that extends BaseActivity. 
I looked in lifecycle of Activity and Fragment. after unlock , onRestart of both BaseActivity and HomeActivity is getting called.

Edit:
I have found
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering
and
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/profile-gpu

But still have doubt, that 
Now i have only one dummy layout file which has no code
still having issue of slow rendering. How is this possible?
layout file look like below

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.app.naam.shop.util.MyTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Some Big scrollable text"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you provide java file or Code?

Comment: Thank you, But It is happening in all activities of Application.